# Apply a function on a column if there are associated with duplicated entries in another column

Tags: r

I have a data set that contains three variables like follows,

```
x=data.frame("a"=c(1,1,2,3),"b"=c("a","b","c","d"),"c"=c(100,100,200,300))
```

If for same value of "a", there are "n" different b values, I would like to divide my "c" value by this "n". That is, I want the output like this,

```
x=data.frame("a"=c(1,1,2,3),"b"=c("a","b","c","d"),"c"=c(50,50,200,300))
```

I know I can try `duplicated()`, but not quite sure how to incorporate it. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We group by 'a' and then divide 'c' by `n_distinct` (number of unique elements) in 'b'

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% 
    group_by(a) %>%
    mutate(c= c/n_distinct(b))
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   a [3]
#      a b         c   new
#  <dbl> <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1 a       100    50
#2     1 b       100    50
#3     2 c       200   200
#4     3 d       300   300
```

Note the above is based on the OP's description (`If for same value of "a", there are "n" different b values`). However, if the OP meant `different` as the total number of elements and not the different values, then instead of `n_distinct`, it would be `n()`.  Here, it is not clear because both conditions work

```
x %>%
   group_by(a) %>%
   mutate(c = c/n())
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
x$c <- x$c/rowSums(table(x[1:2]) > 0)[as.character(x$a)]
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative:

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(x)[, c := c/.N, by="a"][]
#    a b   c
# 1: 1 a  50
# 2: 1 b  50
# 3: 2 c 200
# 4: 3 d 300
```

Another base R:

```
r <- rle(x$a)$lengths
transform(x, c = c/rep(r,r))
#   a b   c
# 1 1 a  50
# 2 1 b  50
# 3 2 c 200
# 4 3 d 300
```

Answer (score 3):

In base R, you can use `ave()`.

```
transform(x, c = c / ave(a, a, FUN = length))
#   a b   c
# 1 1 a  50
# 2 1 b  50
# 3 2 c 200
# 4 3 d 300
```

Comment: Side note, you could use just about any length 4 vector in the first argument of `ave`